# alternatives to exception handling for releasing resources

Tags: c++, exception

I have been learning about how to write exception safe code. Most of the practices suggested like RAII managed memory or mutexes are useful even when we are not using exceptions, as the programmer doesn't have to worry about managing resources manually.

But why do we need exceptions? When we don't get the resources we want, we cannot proceed further, and the process is going to terminate anyways. Then the operating system can worry about releasing the resources. So, what am I missing? what's wrong with my argument?

Comment: Exception is used in the condition you want to recover or retry.

Comment: You assume that an exception will terminate the program.  Sure, no point in cleaning up anything.  What you have to worry about is that it *doesn't* terminate the program.  In other words, when a catch() clause catches it and leaves the program running.  You then better make sure that any objects that went out of scope when the stack was unwound gets destroyed or you'll have a memory leak.  Yes, RAII is the correct pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking for granted that the program can't proceed further when it lacks resources.

If letting the program simply die is an option, then you may not need exceptions. Then again, you might benefit from them even in such a case--throwing an exception lets things get cleaned up so (for example) files you've written will be flushed so you won't loose data that's still in buffers.

For quite a few more cases, just returning to the OS isn't an option. In quite a few cases you'd like to use a resource if possible, but you still need to continue processing even if it's not.